# LiquiBase insert accented characters to Oracle

Tags: oracle, utf-8, liquibase

I'm trying to execute the following insert with LiquiBase:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, value) VALUES (0, 'nullás')
//
```

This is obviously a random value, the goal is to insert non-English, accented characters into a VARCHAR2 column. The target is an Oracle 12c. If I run the insert manually through SQL Developer from my PC, it works OK. But when I run it through LiquiBase from the same PC, it produces the following:

```
null�s
```

Execution log:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, value) VALUES (0, 'null?s')
```

The insert itself is contained in a separate SQL file. It is added to the changeset file like so:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "no" ?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="aaa" >
        <comment>insert.sql</comment>
        <sqlFile dbms="oracle" encoding="UTF-8" path="insert.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" endDelimiter="//" />
    </changeSet>
```

Previously the encoding was set to "utf8", which I think was a typo, but the issue is present after changing it to "UTF-8". Relevant POM settings:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "no" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aaa</groupId>
    <artifactId>aaa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <version.ojdbc>12.2.0.1.0</version.ojdbc>
        <version.org.liquibase.liquibase-maven-plugin>3.6.2</version.org.liquibase.liquibase-maven-plugin>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <liquibase.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.2.3.4:1521/aaa</liquibase.url>
        <!-- liquibase.url>offline:oracle?outputLiquibaseSql=true</liquibase.url -->
        <liquibase.execute.goal>update</liquibase.execute.goal>
        <liquibase.driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</liquibase.driver>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.liquibase.liquibase-maven-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                    <outputFileEncoding>UTF-8</outputFileEncoding>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>file.encoding</name>
                            <value>UTF-8</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.ojdbc}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>liquibase_01</id>
            <properties>
                <liquibase.changeLogFile>liquibase_01.xml</liquibase.changeLogFile>
                <liquibase.username>${admin.shema.name}</liquibase.username>
                <liquibase.password>${admin.shema.password}</liquibase.password>
                <liquibase.migrationSqlOutputFile>target/liquibase/migr_01.sql</liquibase.migrationSqlOutputFile>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>${liquibase.execute.goal}</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I tried the following already:

- Added the `<?xml...` line to all of the xml files, it wasn't added
- Basically all of the UTF-8 configs above were added newly by me
- Added " -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to the maven command line
- Set the MAVEN_OPTS variable to " -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

I'm not sure what else I can try. Is it maybe a setting on the Oracle side? The character set seems to be "AL32UTF8":

```
select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';

AL32UTF8
```

`NLS_LANG` variable is not set on the Oracle server OS.

Oracle itself is installed on a Windows Server 2008 R2 with English localization. Then again, the same LiquiBase version with same runtime environment works very well with an SQL Server 2017 (installed on Windows Server 2016 with English localization), the accented characters are inserted with the same INSERT statement as above. And none of the above detailed UTF-8 settings are enabled on this part of the project.

Comment: Can you examine the actual SQL file `insert.sql` using something like notepad++ to determine the actual encoding of the file? Adding the `encoding` attribute the the `<sqlFile>` element in the changelog won't actually change the encoding of the file, all it does it tell the code to attempt to read it using that encoding. If the file is actually encoded in one of the Windows encodings, then it makes sense that when reading it as UTF-8 it gets converted to the "unknown" character.

Comment: OMG... I can't believe I didn't notice. The SQL file's encoding was ANSI. I changed it to UTF-8 in Notepad++, went through it and fixed the broken accented characters, and now it is also working fine, the various UTF-8 settings were unnecessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was SteveDonie's comment above: file encoding needs to be UTF-8.